# Statusline/Tabline - Unable to see which buffer is open when many buffers are open in a tab

Tags: statusline, plugin-airline

I have a tab with the following window structure:

```
_________________________________
1              | 3               |
               |                 |
               |                 |
_______________|_________________|
4              | 5               | 
               |                 |
               |                 |
_______________|_________________|
```

Numbers indicated the buffer numbers provided automatically by vim. I have `vim-airline` that I was hoping would help me figure out which window I am currently focused on and which buffer I am editing. Please see gif [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LeJt.jpg), reproduced below:

[image]

Buffer 1 is `.vimrc`, 3 is `Main1.cpp`, 4 is `include1.h` and 5 is `include2.h`.

As I move clockwise, the tabline in the bottom of each window gets highlighted indicating which window I am focussed on. However, the tabline does not work properly in buffers/windows 1 and 3. Essentially, in 1 (especially) and 3, I do not get to see `1:.vimrc` and `3:Main1.cpp` in the tablines for these specific windows clearly because the available space is crowded/joslted out unnecessarily for these windows by `4:include1.h` and `5:include2.h`, which are irrelevant in these windows. Is there a way that the tabline can highlight the buffer name completely even if there are other buffers jostling for space on the same tabline?

Because this could be behavior due to possibly some plugins that I have, in the image above, buffer 1 lists all the plugins I have currently installed.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: so, have you configured the tabline?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I only have default settings for these with nothing specific to vim-airline at all in my .vimrc

Comment: according to your screenshot, you have not enabled the tabline feature of vim-airline. Please do so (hint: look into the documentation)

Comment: I looked at the documentation and set `let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1` That indeed shows a highlight on top which highlights which buffer I am on. Thanks for your help! I learned today that a tabline is different from a statusline. Just to cofirm, even if there is only a single tab, the tabline refers to the line on top, that is shared across all windows, while a status line is for each window. Is my understanding correct? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Great, glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Simple fix: don’t include the full buffer or argument list in the status line; save room by just using the current buffer name.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Following https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline, I did
  `let g:airline_section_c='%f %m %l of %L %P'`
  `let g:airline_section_x=''`
  `let g:airline_section_y=''`
  `let g:airline_section_z=''`
So that only sections A, B and C are displayed. I have given empty status message for X, Y and Z. Do you know if there is a way to pass null arguments to section `[...]` on the github page as well?

Comment: @Tryer frankly I’m not sure I follow what you’re asking, but you might also look in the doc file that comes with airline. Use `:helptags ALL`  to make sure `:help` can find it, but then `:help airline_section` or similar might have guidance.

Comment: I also think the default configuration should be useable for the statusline; _i.e._, it shouldn't include the buffer/argument/tab/whatever list in section C.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The default config did not work for me. The image in the OP shows all open buffers in the statusline and hence when I am in the buffer corresponding to the "leftmost", all of the other open buffers crowd out the name of this buffer. I ended up uninstalling vim-airline and having my own custom status line. Do you suggest I delete this question? I don't have a workable answer to the question I myself posed in the OP.

Comment: This could be useful to others… i would leave it. Your custom answer might just inspire others, too, so might be worth adding

Comment: Better solution: drop that garbage and use the default status line and tab line.

Comment: @romainl After a lot of struggle, I have stopped using vim for C/C++ development. I moved back to Visual Studio IDE/VSCode. It was too much to handle and too many conflicts. I use Vim now for (thanks to much of your help over on SO) TEX writing alone.

Comment: If you are happy with your solution maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allows the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Your wish is my command :-)

Comment: Thanks :-) Not everybody knows it is possible after two days or dare ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through ways of customizing the `vim-airline` status line, and also looking at how default vim's inbuilt status lines work, I have ended up using the following in my .vimrc

```
let g:customstatusline = 0 " can be 0 or 1

if g:customstatusline == 0
  let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
  let g:airline_section_c='%f %m %{tagbar#currenttag("%s ","","f")} %l of %L %P'
  let g:airline_section_x=''
  let g:airline_section_y=''
  let g:airline_section_z=''
else
  set laststatus=2
  set statusline=%f\ %m%{tagbar#currenttag('%s\ ','','f')}%l,%L\ %P
  let g:bufferline_active_buffer_left = '[[['
  let g:bufferline_active_buffer_right = ']]]'
endif
```

In the case of `g:customstatusline==0`, I provide a very minimal `vim-airline` that includes the filename of the current buffer only, whether it is modified or not, the current symbol cursor is in (requires `tagbar` plugin), which line the cursor is on currently, how many total lines are in the buffer and what percentage of movement within the buffer is covered. Sections `x`, `y` and `z` of the [status bar](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline#vim-airline) are set to null values. This works for me.

I also found my own custom setting of the status line can also do the job. That is the else case. Here, I display the same content as the case above. The currently active buffer is visually highlighted thus:
`[[[ currently_active_buffer ]]]`